# Tracking user's video bandwidth?

Tags: video, embed

I'm starting my video library in amazon s3. I will give access to embed videos in any site for free. I will only get paid for the bandwidth usage by each user. How can I calculate the bandwidth used by each user ?

If amazon s3 doesn't suit. Please let me know. what is best solution.

Thanks,
Nuwan T.